# Optimizing Microsoft Graph API Integration with LangChain Chatbot

Tags: agent, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

- **Goal**:

  - Integrate Microsoft Graph API with LangChain to enable my chatbot to:

    - List users in groups
    - Show groups a user belongs to
    - Display enterprise applications accessible to a user
- **Current Approach**:

  - Considering using foundation models to generate API endpoints. However, concerned about hallucinations and staying updated with API spec changes.
- **Alternative Idea**:

  - Directly use the [MS Graph openapi spec](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-metadata/blob/master/openapi/v1.0/openapi.yaml) as a tool, following [LangChain's API integration examples](https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/apis).
- **Challenge**:

  - The MS Graph spec is large (30MB), potentially causing:

    - Performance issues
    - Token limits
    - Increased operational costs
- **Question**:

  - What's an efficient way to handle this? Considering trimming the spec to only include relevant calls. Would this be effective?
  - Would chunking and embedding the large spec file buy me anything?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question currently includes multiple questions in one. It should focus on one problem only.